# Read ahead setting on Solaris

Tags: solaris, hard-disk, performance, disk

How to get the current read ahead setting on Solaris?

On Linux it can be retrieved like this:

```
# echo $(($(blockdev --getra /dev/sda)*512/1024))
```

(Assuming that blockdev always returns the read-head value in 512 byte units.)

(Usually the read ahead is 128K on Linux.)

Answer (score 2):

Solaris may do more or less read ahead. In contrary to Linux, Solaris is fully dynamic in the kernel and decides what to do based on constraints and available kernel memory.

There is also a read ahead that is controlled by the filesystem and there may be a different cache than the historical cache if you use e.g. ZFS.

For a better answer, it would be important whether you really like to read buffered devices which does not look reasonable and it would be important to know why you like to know something about an implementation detail.

In general on Solaris, read() calls to buffered background storage are converted into a copy from a transient kernel mapping mapping area. On a 32 bit kernel IIRC this transient mapping area is 2 MB, on 64 bit kernels it is larger. Read ahead operations are implemented via manually fired fault calls that are set up by the related segment driver (the driver that is between virtual foreground memory and background storage). AFAIK, the only available description is in my WOFS diploma thesis. It was used by Sun employees for that reason.

To make thing better to understand, it may help to know the historical background:

28 years ago, SunOS-4.0 was published with a new virtual memory subsystem. All modern OS copy at least the mmap() idea from SunOS-4.0. SunOS-4.0 however is more as it implements an object oriented VM subsystem.

There is virtual foreground memory, a segment driver, the HAL layer (MMU) and the background storage.

Depending on the foreground memory object type and the background object type, there is a special segement driver.

If you have a filesystem as foreground object and disk storage as background memory, the segment driver is called `seg_vn`. If you have a mapping to a device, `sev_dev` is used.

To understand that the readahead is object specific, you may like to check `ufs_vnops.c` and look for `ufs_getpage_ra()`.

Comment: And there is now way to print the effective read ahead for a certain file system (taking all those constraints into account)?

Comment: @maxschlepzig For ZFS, read http://www.cuddletech.com/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=1040 For example:  *... if read a block we prefetch the next block. If you read that block we just prefetched, we go and grab 2 blocks. Got those blocks? Grab 3. Its more intelligent than this, but you get the idea. This can go all the way up to prefetching 256 blocks at a time. ...*  And that's just ZFS file-level prefetch.  ZFS also has device-level prefetch.  There's also sd-device readahead, which is also dynamic.  Also SAMFS/QFS with all its tunables.  Solaris has no one "effective read ahead".

Comment: @maxschlepzig If you don't explain us why you are interested in this information, it seems that there is no more information that could be given.